# what is the time complexity of iterator increments and decrements for stl::map

Tags: stl, iterator, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

My understanding is that map is implemented as a binary search tree.
So increment is finding the next bigger key. Vice the verse for decrements. 
Is the operation log(n) time complexity? If not, how is this implemented?

Comment: It just follows the tree. The iterator doesn't even has access to the comparison function.

Comment: I meant exactly following the tree. But, it takes log(n) to follow the tree, it it not?

Comment: Going from one node to the next one shouldn't involve more than following a pointer. In any cases, stored values are not read, and keys are not compared.